# Magento Store filter in Order grid?

Tags: filter

We have tried to add store filter in order list page admin section. But not able to get solution.

How to add store filter in order grid?. Is it possible for this?
Please help.

Comment: You can get some idea from here :- http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/65150/store-filter-column

Answer (score 1):

Just Rewrite class ***Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid*** .

On  add below code at `_prepareColumns()`..

> ```
> <?php
> class StackExchange_AdvanceCustomerGrid_Block_Adminhtml_Sales_Order_Grid
>  extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid{
> protected function _prepareColumns()
>   {
>
>       $this->addColumnAfter('store_id',array(
>               'header' => 'Store',
>               'index' => 'store_id',
>               'type'  => 'options',
>               'width' => '70px',
>               'options'   => Mage::getModel('core/store')->getCollection()->toOptionHash(),
>
>       ),'shipping_name');
>
>        parent::_prepareColumns();
>        return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareColumns();
>   }
> }
> ```